# Why use "setLayoutParams" after "getLayoutParams"?

Tags: android, layoutparams

For example, if you want to change `LayoutParams` of some view to `WRAP_CONTENT` for both `width` and `height` programmatically, it will look something like this:

```
 final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = yourView.getLayoutParams();
 lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
 lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

As I understood `getLayoutParams` returns a reference for Params, so this code would be enough. But I often see in examples and so on that after this lines, this one follows:

```
 yourView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

And I wonder what is the point of this line?

Is this just for the sake of better code readability or are there cases when it won't work without it?

Comment: I vote readability. Though, I've never seen these examples where existing views are having to be dynamically resized. I usually see views being dynamically added to the content view. In those cases, setLayoutParams is needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is used because `setLayoutParams()` also trigger `resolveLayoutParams()` and `requestLayout()`, which will notify the view that something has changed and refresh it.

Otherwise we can't ensure that the new layout parameters are actually updated.

---

See `View.setLayoutParams` sources code:

```
public void setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (params == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Layout parameters cannot be null");
    }
    mLayoutParams = params;
    resolveLayoutParams();
    if (mParent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ((ViewGroup) mParent).onSetLayoutParams(this, params);
    }
    requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: So basically we need it only if view has been already drawn, and we need to change it afterwards?

Comment: Yes. Call it when changing a existed view parameters in runtime

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ensure that any change you made to LayoutParams that returned by `getLayoutParams()` will be reflected correctly. It can be varied by Android version. So you have to call `setLayoutParams()` to make sure the view will update those changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the setLayoutParams(), your layout setting would be effective when the [View.onLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) is called.

Here is the source code of [View.setLayoutParams()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)):

```
public void setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {  

    if (params == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Layout parameters cannot be null");
    }
    mLayoutParams = params;
    resolveLayoutParams();
    if (mParent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ((ViewGroup) mParent).onSetLayoutParams(this, params);
    }
    requestLayout();
}`
```

As you see, the `requestLayout` would be called in the `setLayoutParams`. This view would be relayout again immediately. The `onLayout` would be also called.